# Dynamic serialization of selected fields for java objects based on a dynamic list with field names

Tags: java, serialization, java-8, jackson, gson

I'm trying to find a solution to an issue wherein I want to serialize java objects with selected fields based on a separate list of "Fields to include". For example I have a java object class as follows:

```
@Data
public class ModelA implements Serializable {
    private String fieldAA;
    private String fieldAB;
    private ModelB fieldAC;
    private ModelC fieldAD;
}

@Data
public class ModelB implements Serializable {
    private String fieldBA;
    private String fieldBB;
    private String fieldBC;
}

@Data
public class ModelC implements Serializable {
    private String fieldCA;
    private String fieldCB;
}
```

And a list of "Fields to include" - *List<String> as ["fieldAA", "fieldBA", "fieldBB", "fieldCB"]*, I want to serizlize ModelA to only include fields from this list and ignore rest, like:

```
{
    "fieldAA": "Value 1",
    "fieldAC": {
        "fieldBA": "Value 2",
        "fieldBB": "Value 3"
    },
    "fieldAD": {
        "fieldCB": "Value 4"
    }
}
```

Thing is, the dynamic list of fields to include can change from request to request, and I only want to serialize fields which are present in this list. You can assume for now that there are finite set of requests which require a given set of response, but their number is still quite large (assume >50) to make different data transfer objects for each, when most of them logically share multiple fields as they refer similar data. (Saying this in case some kind of pool of serializers is possible)

I **do not** want to annotate/change modifiers of fields in model class as any field in the class can serialized for one request and not for other, so in a way each field is important for at least one request.

I understand some custom implementation of Jackson's ObjectMapper or Gson while serializing the request is the way to go (if not any other solution is also appreciated), but I'm unable to find any good resources to achieve this. Looking for something that does not impact performance very heavily (although anything will do if that is not possible).

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: There is no such a thing in Gson. The easiest, but not the most efficient, way of doing so is serializing the models into an intermediate JSON tree, and let it retain only the fields you want removing the rest. Manipulating the JSON tree is pretty straightforward and can be easily aligned with the list you're mentioning.

Comment: Is there any other library which can help with this apart from GSON? @fluffy

Comment: No clue. Did you try to apply a workaround I was suggesting?